# How to push golang binary files to nexus repository from jenkinsfile?

Tags: go, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have a problem when using golang, and nexus as the repository. it's different from maven which can download and push automatically to nexus, while golang can't automatically push when the module has been downloaded and the project binary has been built.

is there a way to push binary files into the in nexus golang repository?

Comment: Maybe create a raw repository und then upload the binary via POST/PUT? E.g. as it's done here:  
https://gist.github.com/claudiosteuernagel/fff0641ae51f1d55d9fc59aa7175e56e?

Comment: Can it be pulled later when I've uploaded it to Nexus? the problem is i need it for additional dependencies to the golang project